# How to send (pre defined) message to telegram with hyperlink from webpage

Tags: telegram, message

I like to send a pre defined text to my telegram bot with a hyperlink from my website.

It's kind of a song on request system what I am trying to make from my website

<a href="https://t.me/share/url?url=Ring of Fire by Johnny Cash" (This works but is not addressed to a user id or botname)

[https://api.telegram.org/bot[Bot-Api-code]/sendMessage?chat_id=[@......]&text=[test]](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BBot-Api-code%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=%5B@......%5D&text=%5Btest%5D)

[https://t.me/bot[Bot-Api-code]/sendMessage?chat_id=[@......]&text=[test]](https://t.me/bot%5BBot-Api-code%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=%5B@......%5D&text=%5Btest%5D)